SQL Bulk Insert Saves extra character
i use this code for Bulk Insert
BULK INSERT [Table]
FROM 'D:\phones.txt'
WITH
(
   ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
)

My data has only one column of 10 characters
For example
| 1234567890 |    
| 1234567891 |    
| 1234567892 |

After saving in the database, by running the following code, it shows the length of the data more
SELECT TOP (1)
[Phone]
,LEN([Phone]) AS Phonelength
FROM [Table]

result



Phone
Phonelength




1234567891
11



The extra character added to the end of the field is the new line
Why is the new line added?

look with an hexeditor what the libeendings reallx are windows uses CRLF

no i thunk  0x0d0x0a or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Please add details about the target table; see [mcve] for details.

in my case
I opened the file with the hexeditor, each line ended with [0d 0a]
So I modified the following line in this way
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0d0a'

